# How to turn off the timer sound on my Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100

I need to use the self timer but I would not like it to beep as it counts down. (You know, the long beep and then the short beeps right before it takes the picture.) Is there a way to turn the sound off?

Answer (score 2):

In [the manual, page 144](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16910/~/reference-manual---d3100); if you turn off the Beep setting in the setup menu, the self-timer beep will not sound.

There does not appear to be a way to toggle this beep and leave other sounds, like focus confirmation.